# pass the parameter to mail tempate in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, email

I want to pass sql data as parameter in mail template.  'welcome.blade.php' is my mail template.I have created mail file as 'Remainder.php'Now I caught 'internal server error' .I want to pass users data to welcome.blade.php

call the mail function in ajax

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
            url: "testHello",
            data: {'id':user_id},
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               //alert(data);
        }
          });
```

route

```
  Route::get('testHello','travelerHome@test');
```

Controller

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $request_data = $request->all();
   $id = $request_data['id'];  
   $to_email = 'test.test@domain.com';
    Mail::to($to_email)->send(new Reminder);
    return response()->json($id);  
}
```

Remailder.php

```
public function build()
{
    DB::enableQueryLog();
 
$users = DB::table('travel_request')
        ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
        ->join('users', 'travel_request.approver_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('travel_purpose', 'travel_request.travel_purpose_id', '=', 'travel_purpose.id')
        ->join('traveling_details', 'travel_request.id','=','traveling_details.travel_request_id' )
        ->join('country','country.id', '=', 'traveling_details.country_id')
        ->join('travel_type','traveling_details.travel_type_id', '=', 'travel_type.id')
        ->join('travel_request_status','travel_request.status_id', '=', 'travel_request_status.id')
        ->select('travel_request.*', 'travel_request.id as travel_id','department.name as dept_name','users.firstname as approver_name','travel_purpose.purpose','country.name as country_name','traveling_details.from_date','traveling_details.to_date','travel_request_status.status','travel_type.type as travelType')->where('travel_request.approver_id',$approver_id)->groupby('travel_request.id')->get(); 
    return $this->from('test.larvel@domain.com')
                ->view('email.welcome',['users'=>$users]);
}
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@foreach ($users as $user) 
     {{$user->traveler_name}}
     @endforeach
```

Comment: If you got `internal server error` it means that something went wrong. Did you check the logs on your server?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an undefined variable ($approver_id) in your query.
Your code looks ok, I assume the query is throwing that 'internal server error'.

If you check your logs, you should be able to pinpoint the issue.